# Prevent window well from flooding in old house without weeping tile

Tags: basement, foundation, flooding

When it rains heavily the window well in the front of my house fills with water, leading to flooding from the window. The window well is covered so water from the roof should not be filling it. A contractor suggested digging it out and filling it with stones past the bottom of the foundation. Is this a good option or will it lead to hydrostatic pressure on the foundation? The house is from the 1940s so there is no weeping tile to drain into.

Comment: Photos would help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: how clean and operational are your gutters?

Comment: Transparent "dones" are available for window wells to keep rain out. If that isn't enough, I think you're looking at reconstructing the window wells so they drain better and/or reworking water flow around your house so it doesn't get into the well in the first place.

Comment: The water is coming from *somewhere.*  Maybe you need to do some more regrading or add a french drain and/or gutters.